# MySQL Remote Connections & Dynamic IP

Tags: networking, mysql

I'm just configuring a remote test machine for my development team.

As not being a administration guru I faced one issue only (and I'm really proud of it).

We have dynamic IP addresses in the office - how to allow remote connections in such situation? I have no idea how to solve it - tried Google for that but did not find working solution yet. Any suggestions?

Cheers,
Steffen

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make dynamic IP address fixed?](http://superuser.com/questions/211955/make-dynamic-ip-address-fixed) also [How can a computer with dynamic IP work as a webserver?](http://superuser.com/questions/20580/how-can-a-computer-with-dynamic-ip-work-as-a-webserver)

Comment: By remote connections, do you mean remote from the same network, or remote from other networks (ie, over the internet). What OS is the server using and what OS are the clients using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, there is suppport for dynamic IP in [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) (remote desktop app).

Or you could use [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/dyndns-free/) to handle your dynamic IP.